Headers and footers colliding
Im using html and CSS to print documents, I have to print the header and the footer on each page, which works but if the headers goes beyond a certain height, the content gets rendered on top of the header.
This is the template that i created.


window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const header = document.getElementById("header");
    const footer = document.getElementById("footer");

    const headerHeight = header.scrollHeight + 20;
    const footerHeight = footer.scrollHeight + 20;

    document.getElementById("page-header").style.height = headerHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("page-header-space").style.height = headerHeight + "px";

    document.getElementById("page-footer").style.height = footerHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("page-footer-space").style.height = footerHeight + "px";
});
.page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0mm;
    width: 100%;
}

@page {
    margin: 15pt
}

@media print {
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    tfoot {
        display: table-footer-group;
    }

    button {
        display: none;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
<body>

  <div class="page-header" id="page-header">
      <div id="header">
          <!-- HEADER HTML GOES HERE-->
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page-footer" id="page-footer">
      <div id="footer">
          <!-- FOOTER HTML GOES HERE -->
      </div>
  </div>

  <table>

      <thead>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <!--place holder for the fixed-position header-->
                  <div id="page-header-space" class="page-header-space"></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <!--*** CONTENT GOES HERE ***-->
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
                  <div class="page-footer-space" id="page-footer-space"></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>

  </table>
</body>



I've tried other methods like using libraries such as selectpdf (slow), ironPdf (expensive) and others but they just don't seem to hit the mark. So I decided to give it a try myself.
